# CTMC: Calculating Steady State probabilities with multiple BSCCs

Tags: logic, markov-chains

I am currently studying this [course chapter 5.3](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_919906c7dae904d0de0a93d36bf050f1_modelchecking.pdf?Expires=1481241600&Signature=P2ejG~WSLj0bmmhka2k1UisOup7YOq7AiIkoQuGmSXrtOubM~HIKb2Oac9ld2wI91B8hg79PH3hAhtSaNObiTmzlLiNMa9XZB8cBv0g3N0kMnuxsG-PHIUxU8zQFFd4T4SwcqAqlqZc921z~KCWIeOROPjtXmTSrvqdw7cpO92Y_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A). I have this labeled CTMC (Continuous-Time Markov Chains) with three BSCCs (bottom strongly connected components). Let's say we want to calculate the steady-state probability of being in a state with the label ***{a}***.

[image: CTMC Example]

We know that the states s1, s2 and s5 hold the label ***{a}***. s2 is a transient state, so we are only interested in B1 and B3.

---

Using the equation below:
[image]

We derive one of the solutions is:
[image]

---

**My question is how did we get 2/3? In other words, how did we get 2/3 from Pr{reach B1 from s0)?**

Comment: Maybe clear to someone else, but to me, it is completely unclear how that diagram even translates into a discrete time markov chain, much less a continuous time one.

Comment: @DanielV Thanks for trying to help. From what I understand, the numbers in the links represent the transition rate because it's continuous but in discrete the outgoing transition in a state should sum to 1. If we want to get rate matrix, 1st row would be something like: {0,1,1,0,0,0}.

Comment: The only way I know continuous time discrete state systems is if you have a matrix $M$ representing an infinitesimal change over infinitesimal time, then the steady state is $S = \int M^{dt} = \exp ~ \int (\ln M) ~ dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confess, it took me too long to admit how much, but I got it:

First of all, that $B_3$ is wrong, it's still $B_1$, then just solve
$$x = \frac 1 2 \cdot 1 + \frac 1 2 \cdot\frac 1 2 \cdot x$$

If we are reading the same document (the link you posted is broken), then you can find the same in the next paragraph [(click me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kYkt.png).

This time, that $B_1$ is wrong, it's still $B_3$, then just solve
$$x = \frac 1 2 \cdot \left( \frac 1 2 \cdot x + \frac 1 4 \right)$$